# How to post particular data format to rest wcf json services in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, wcf

i need to post below type of format,and getting the json data

```
{
    "Authentication": {
      "Username": "testUser@123",
      "Password": "testPassword@123"
    },
    "RequestType": 4
  }
```

and am using the following code to post to wcf web services,

```
    NSData *__jsonData = nil;
    NSString *__jsonString = nil;
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://adservicetest.azurewebsites.net/order/"];


    dict = @{@"Authentication":@{@"Username":email.text,@"Password":password.text},@"FileID": [NSNumber numberWithInt:fileID],@"RequestType":[NSNumber numberWithInt:requestType]};

  if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict])
    {
        __jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
      __jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:__jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"Error %@", __jsonString);
    }

    // Be sure to properly escape your url string.

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: __jsonData];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [__jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSError *errorReturned = nil;
    NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];

    if (errorReturned)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", errorReturned);
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *responseString=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
    }
```

But am getting null responseString value and also i have tested this post method using chrome advanced rest client its working,please correct where am doing wrong.am unable to solve this issue from past 2 days. Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your NSURL and please let me know more queries :)

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://adservicetest.azurewebsites.net/order/json/process"];
```

Response will be:

```
Jason Data = {"Authentication":{"Password":"testPassword@123","Username":"testUser@123"},"RequestType":4}
2015-01-21 14:40:09.166 TestProject[2036:529966] strAddr = {"Errors":[],"StatusCode":200,"StatusMessage":"Get Orders List processed successfully","Files":[{"FileID":28,"Borrower":{"FirstName":"Ram","LastName":"Varma","PhoneNumbers":{"HomePhone":"5122154434","WorkPhone":"5124848340"},"Email":"ram@vonexpy.com"},"CoBorrower":{"FirstName":"Nadeem","LastName":"Shaik","PhoneNumbers":{"HomePhone":"5122154434","WorkPhone":"04065474405"},"Email":"nadeem@vonexpy.com"},"LenderDetails":{"LenderName":"VonExpy","LenderAddress":{"Address1":"101 ","Address2":"meghna ","City":"hyd","State":"AP","Zip":"500033"}},"LoanDetails":{"LoanType":"Housing","LoanPurpose":"business","LoanNumber":"VonExpy"},"PropertyAddress":{"Address1":"hyd","Address2":"guntur","City":"jubilee ","State":"UP","Zip":"87957"},"PropertyEstimatedValue":"fhy76","Orders":[{"OrderID":28,"AppraiserID":"27","AppraiserName":"FirstCLose","ProductDetails":{"ProductType":"hudy","FHACaseNumber":"746tr65"},"DueDate":"43543","InspectionDate":"983482374","Fee":"034202","NotesList":[],"Status":4,"Documents":[],"Condition":"987hkkk","ApplicationId":1,"ApplicationOrderId":"88"}]}]}
```

Comment: you need more help let me know

Comment: How can i filter the above json data using status, if the status is 4 that related data should display on tableview and if the status is 5 that related data should display on tableview. how can i achieve this.

Comment: You need to use NSJSONSerialization and it will return dictionary or array of your response, then you can check for status key what is the value and use it further

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check below output and let me know your query resolved or not.

Please use below code and comment your code and then your can convert NSData to your required data format.

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"strAddr = %@", responseString);

       // NSString *responseString=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:&errorReturned];
       // NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
      //  NSLog(@"Error %@", errorReturned);

Printing description of responseString:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Service</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p xmlns="">Endpoint not found. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="http://adservicetest.azurewebsites.net/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but its not solved. i need to get json data, i dont know why its showing this message. Can u help?

Comment: Hi, When you try to copy paste this url http://adservicetest.azurewebsites.net/order/ in browser, Http page will be displayed and we get the same page in response.
Can you please share more details about your request so that i can help you